# How to increment a javascript variable from a .php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, variables

So i'm in a bit of a dilemma, I have a script where I am trying to make a javascript variable increment by 1 when a special function is called. The problem is that this incrementian, can only happen if another function is happening in a .php script, as I want to make sure it only happens when this function is called. Now my problem/dilemma is I know I am able to take this javascript variable and send it to the .php script and then access it this way, there is just two ways of doing this, either making a function in the javascript and then call that function through the .php script, or access the javascript variable and then do the incrementing through the .php script. What would be the best way, passing the variable or the function and how can this be done? I have a "POST" form which submits a couple of other values to the .php script, and I know you can use the form to pass them but again I am not sure how.

So far my scripts look like below.

html/javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

                <div class="myVar">
                    myVar: $<span id="myVar"></span>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript"> 

                    var myVar= 1; // this is the variable I want to do the incremention to
                    document.getElementById("myVar").innerHTML = myVar;
                    document.getElementByID("myVar").value = myVar;

                    /*
                    function addOne() {
                        myVar= myVar+1;
                        document.getElementById("myVar").innerHTML = myVar;
                    }
                */
                </script>

                <!-- FORM FOR SUBMIT START-->

                    <form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="payment-form">
                    <input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
                    <input type="image"  src="BuyButton1.png" id="customButton" value="pay" alt="button"/>
                    </form>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function isNumberKey(evt)
                    {
                    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                    return false;

                    return true;
                    }
                    </script>

                 <!--FORM FOR SUBMIT ENDING-->
</body>

</html>
```

php:

```
<?php 

    require_once('./stripe-php/init.php');

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("secret code removed");

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $myAmount = $_POST['amount'];
    $describtion = $_POST['description'];

    $myAmount = round((int)$myAmount*100,0);

    try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $myAmount, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $describtion));

    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    }

?>
```

Comment: If you want to run the PHP script without submitting the form, use AJAX. Otherwise, put the value in a hidden input in the form, and when you submit the form the form the PHP code can increment it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ajax function (js) to call your php function, and use it's output to be fed back into your javascript.

A bit of jQuery code to give you an idea how this could work.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/somescript?value=1"
})
  .done(function( data ) {
      alert('php script returned: ' + data);
  });
```

Comment: Of course this works without jQuery as well. There are plenty of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a hidden `input` in your form instead of using a variable:

```
<?php
   $myVar = intval($_POST['myVar'] ? $_POST['myVar'] : 0) + 1;
   //other PHP stuff
?>
```

And then add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="myVar" value="<?= $myVar?> />
```

And then access the hidden field with Javascript:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('myVar').value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a quick question. will this save by it self so that whenever I go to the site, it will be updated to the newest amount or do I have to make a save function too?

Comment: No, you need to use a cookie or localStorage for that.

Comment: I have tested you code, I don't get any errors but when displaying the value it shows as "undefined"?